# Git push gives 403 error

Tags: apache-http-server, git

I have been following the steps on [Hosting a Git server under Apache on Windows](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/07/31/hosting-a-git-server-under-apache-on-windows/) and got everything working fine. I then wanted to add in a basic authentication for push requests and so made changes following the solution given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817478/setting-up-git-server-on-windows-with-git-http-backend-exe) to my `httpd.conf` file and created a user with a password.

But when I try to push to my repository (on localhost) I get a 403 error. Why might this be?

The addition at the end of my `httpd.conf` file is below.

```
# Local git repository setup

# Git repository information
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT C:/Repositories
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAliasMatch \
"(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | info/refs | objects/(info/[^/]+ | [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}.(pack|idx)) | git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
"C:/Program Files/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/$1"

# Allow cloning of repository without authentication
<Directory />
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Authentication
<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-receive-pack$">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Login"
    AuthUserFile "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/passwords/git_passwords"
    Require user alec
</LocationMatch>
```

Also, I have seen questions like this both on SuperUser and StackOverflow. If someone could tell me which site it is suited to more that would be great.

**Edit**

Checking the apache error log reveals this error

```
AH01215: Service not enabled: 'receive-pack'
```

**Solution with new problem**
Adding `SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER` allows me to push to the repo but I never get asked for a password...

Answer (score 3):

Finally got things working (although I'm not entirely sure how). The changes to my `httpd.conf` file are at the end like this:

```
# Local git repository setup

# Git repository information
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT C:/Repositories
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
ScriptAliasMatch \
"(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | info/refs | objects/(info/[^/]+ | [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}.(pack|idx)) | git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
"C:/Program Files/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/$1"

# Allow cloning of repository without authentication
<Directory />
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Authentication
<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-receive-pack$">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Login"
    AuthUserFile "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/passwords/git_passwords"
    Require user alec
</LocationMatch>
<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-upload-pack$">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Login"
    AuthUserFile "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/passwords/git_passwords"
    Require user alec
</LocationMatch>
```

It appears that a key line was `SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER`

Answer (score 0):

You have a location match for `git-receive-pack` but not for `git-upload-pack`. Do the same `LocationMatch` block for `git-upload-pack` as well.

Comment: Just tried adding the same block immediately after with `git-upload-pack` instead of `git-receive-pack` but still get the same error. I've added the apache error log, does that explain it?

Comment: @Kvothe hmm.. I will investigate further, in that case.